# ListView/RecyclerView item expand animation one by one on scroll?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-animation, expandablerecyclerview

Hey Every one I am working on a project that requires ListView/RecyclerView items animation in a very unique. Here is the sample app [RetailMeNot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whaleshark.retailmenot&hl=en). The ListView or RecyclerView used in this app is definitely custom and looks pretty cool. Initially, the list show smaller image of a child-item. As the user scrolls up, the child item expands fully to reveal a bigger image and previously expand item collapse/hide and put the next item on top.

Has anyone seen a library or implementation of a similar ListView/RecyclerView?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I really tried hard to make this effect on ListView and RecyclerView but couldn't achieve the required result.....

Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

After doing so much search and trying so many example's I finally created the effect with this [library](https://github.com/iielse/RetailMeNotList). This library has the same expand/collapse effect as **[RetailMeNot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whaleshark.retailmenot&hl=en)**. Just download the library and use it in your project.

Happy Coding!!!